# InfluxDB templating query - referring to measuerments?

Tags: templating, influxdb, grafana

I'm trying to make templates for my dahboards, and I have problems when it comes to referring to measuerment names.

My variables:

```
$space = SHOW MEASUREMENTS
```

Then I would like a variable that contains only values from a specific `$space`, which is actually a `MEASUREMENT`:

```
$app = SHOW TAG VALUES WITH KEY = "Application" WHERE MEASUREMENT =~ /^$space$/
```

Here I get a message: `Template variables could not be initialized: error parsing query: found MEASUREMENT, expected identifier, string, number, bool at line 1, char 48`

In the official example it is like this, though it refers to another tag:

```
$datacenter = SHOW TAG VALUES WITH KEY = "datacenter"
$host = SHOW TAG VALUES WITH KEY = "hostname" WHERE "datacenter" =~ /^$datacenter$/
```

I cannot find any info how to refer to `MEASUREMENTS` which would work. `WHERE`, `WITH`, etc.. Maybe is it not possible at all?
I found only this in the official tutorial, but this is for keys, not values.

```
SHOW TAG KEYS [FROM <measurement_name>]
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured it out:

```
SHOW TAG VALUES FROM  /^$space$/ WITH KEY = "Application"
```